# How to crawl a group of websites looking for CSP issues?

Tags: content-security-policy

We have started implementing CSP headers on some client sites, firstly in report-only mode. My disinclination to turn it on into live mode is because we may break the clients website because we missed something.
Is there a script (similar to cURL) which I can use to check for CSP issues (similar to the Google Webmaster Tools-> Console), so I can scan entire sites quickly?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to being able to crawl, such a script would need to apply the CSP rules and send reports or log violations in some way. I don't know about any such scripts. In addition there are differences between browsers in how CSP is implemented, both CSP level and various implementation choices. So even though you can scan the entire website without findings there could theoretically still be violations reported from other browsers.

If your main concern is the sources loaded you could build a script that extracts all the source URLs. This would still be a time consuming task to write and fine tune regex to first filter out comments and XML namespace URLs, then apply another regex to find the actual source URL. The output would have to be checked against your policy, likely a manual process. Finally you would also need to check script and style files to find potential violations there. I have done this in a script looking for http references in client code. It is a massive task that will likely consume more hours than updating the CSP once violations occur.

As you already have a CSP in report-only mode your confidence with the policy will grow over time as real users interact with the websites. Keep the report-only policy and add a more permissive enforced policy. As confidence grows, make the enforced policy stricter by making it more similar to the report-only version. Whenever violations occur, check if they can be reproduced is just something that happens on selected clients due to specific browsers, browser extensions, rewrites by proxies etc.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any advantage to running in report-only mode on prod (so violations don't break the site, and in full mode on a development environment? I know this negates the benefits of CSP, but I never want the client to see a broken site through an oversight of theirs not telling us about a new integration.

Comment: Even though report-only mode doesn't give any of the protections that an enforced CSP will bring, it enabled you to safely test the CSP out in the prod environment. Using the enforced mode in development ensures that new dependencies are found before reaching prod.

Answer (score 1):

You can scan entire site quickly by use a simple JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
Current Url: <span id='url'></span><br>
<iframe id='site' src='about:blank' onload='reload()' width='100%' height='400px'></iframe>
<script nonce="test">
var page =0;
var pages = [  // Urls from sitemap.xml
'https://example.com', 'https://example.com/csp/', 'https://example.com/es/',
'https://example.com/en/', 'https://example.com/csp/about/', 'https://example.com/contacts/'
];

function reload() {
  if (page < pages.length) {
    document.getElementById('url').innerHTML = pages[page];
    document.getElementById('site').src = pages[page];
    page = page+1;
    }
  else {
    document.getElementById('url').innerHTML = 'All done';
    document.getElementById('site').onload = "";
    document.getElementById('site').src = "about:blank";
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Since scanned web site is load in `<iframe>`, it need to remove `frame-ancestors` and `X-Frame-Options` header if present.

This script can be used in any browser, but `onclick`/`onmouseover`/etc events will not fire. Also forms will not be filled and submitted. Therefore, not all possible CSP violations will be detected by scanning.

You have to check violation reports during 2 weeks or more before switch CSP to enforce mode.

You can inject this script into scanned website itself and do not use `<iframe>` (use `onpageload` event instead of `onload`).